# JDBC ignores username on connection to localhost

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

If I'm accesing my local MySQL databse via `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` i get the error message `java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'mydb'`.

I have also tried using the parameter `&user=crm`.
If i use the extrernal ip i can login without problems.
I am using `mysql-connector-java:6.0.5`

Am I missing something?

```
private static Connection connect;

public static Connection getDatabaseConnection() {
    if (connect == null) {
        try {
            connect = DriverManager
                    .getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb?serverTimezone=Europe/Berlin","crm",null);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return connect;
}
```

EDIT: add portnumber even tho it dose not fix the problem

EDIT2:

```
mysql>     select user,host from mysql.user;
+------+-----------+
| user | host      |
+------+-----------+   
| crm  | %         |
| root | 127.0.0.1 |
| root | ::1       |
|      | localhost |
| pma  | localhost |
| root | localhost |
+------+-----------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

EDIT3: 
If the password is not `null` and not an empty `String` the username is used. mayby its a `mysql-connector-java:6.0.5` bug

EDIT4:
The problem is not `mysql-connector-java:6.0.5` since i get the same bahavour if I'm using the standard MySQL cli client. I log into the databse with `mysql -u crm` and i get a shell. If i now try to change to the `mydb` database i get the following error

```
mysql> use mydb
ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'mydb'
```

even if im manualy setting the permissions i still get the same error

```
 GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `mydb`.* TO 'crm'@'%';
```

for some reason MySQL dont like my non exsisting password

Comment: Please mention port number after localhost (jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb...)

Comment: Sorry but this dose not help but thanks anyway. Like i have sayd in my Question: If im changing the address to the ip address of the NIC (i my case 192.168.1.22) its working even without the port.

Comment: @SachinSarawgi That is the default, and if the port number was wrong he would hardly be getting this exception.

Answer (score 0):

The user "crm" host column may not be set to accept request from localhost.

Please run following MySQL command:

> select user,host from mysql.user;

Check if in place of host "%" is their or not.
If not run following commands:

> update mysql.user set host="%" where user="crm";
>
> select user,host from mysql.user;

Now it should show "%".

Hope it helps.

Comment: @Albritter does it help?? If not please tell me, I will try different thing.

Comment: Sorry to keep you waiting.

Comment: Unfortunatly it does not help.

Comment: Let me try different thing, while I try please try to read [link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-usagenotes-connect-drivermanager.html). May help

Comment: @Albritter from your error it seems that its not showing user name when giving exception. It saying that ''@'localhost'. Generally it says like 'root'@'localhost'.

Answer (score -1):

```
String url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/your_Database";
String userName="crm"
String password=""
```

Please try above connection.Let me know if it works.